# What is the space that exponents of ElGamal encryption scheme live?

Tags: elgamal-encryption, group-theory

It is a bit stupid question, but I am so confused. Please examine my explanation. What is the space that exponents the generator $g$ of a cyclic group $G$ of prime order $p$?

I think it is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ since $|G|=p$, so that $G=\{g^0, g^1, \ldots, g^{p-1}\}$. Thus the space that the exponents live is $\mathbb{Z}_p$, which is a field.

But here is what I am confused. By Fermat's little theorem, $\forall a\in \mathbb{Z}_p-\{0\}, a^{p-1}\equiv 1 (mod \,p)$. Is this also holds for $g^{p-1}$? Namely, is $g^{p-1}\equiv 1 (mod \, p)$?

I think it isn't, because the statement of Fermat's little theorem is about power of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, which is an additive cyclic group of order $p$, but in the ElGamal case, we are dealing with multiplicative cyclic group of order $p$.

Please examine my statements whether I am correct or not.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have observed by Fermat we have $g^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$, however we also know that $g^0\equiv 1\pmod p$ so that $g^0$ and $g^{p-1}$ represent the same element of $G$. Therefore $|G|=p-1$ and the exponents lie in $\mathbb Z/(p-1)\mathbb Z$.

Comment: But then, why is (the order of $G$)=$p$? Isn't it a group of order $p-1$?

Comment: The order of $g$ is $p-1$ and $G$ is a group of order $p-1$

Comment: Thank you. I think I had some imprecise understanding in mathematical notations.